# Java JDBC: connect cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, jdbc

Error occurs while trying to use the following code:

```
Connection.connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectivityUrl,"root","root");
Statement state  = connect.createStatement();
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>   connect cannot be resolved or is not a field
>   connect cannot be resolved
>
> at DbConnectivity.main(DbConnectivity.java:15)

Comment: how is this javascript related? how is this mysql or selenium related?

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `Connection connect = `, creating a variable? A typo?

Comment: Please read your compiler output carefully. This is not going to help anybody else. It's just a typo, nothing for asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

left side variable declaration not correct. it should be like below

```
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectivityUrl,"root","root");
```